# subprocess improperly interpreting MacOS `/private` directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, filesystems

I'm stumped on an interesting issue: I am attempting to execute a command that copies a local file to a Postgres Docker container. The code:

```py
command = "docker cp /tmp/app/dump.sql postgres-app:/tmp/postgres/backup/"
process = subprocess.Popen(
    shlex.split(command), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE
)
stdout, stderr = process.communicate()
```

Strangely, `stderr` returns:

```
lstat /private/tmp/app/dump.sql: no such file or directory
```

I am executing these commands from this directory on my Mac:

```
/Users/my-name/path/to/project
```

Based on my research, the `/private` directory referenced in the error [appears to be a Mac filesystem feature](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/227869). It seems that the incorrect directory reference (with `/private` prepended) is being passed to the subprocess by Python, and I am unsure of how I can correct that.

Thanks for any and all help... I am testing this functionality locally, but this file will eventually be deployed to a vanilla Linux environment where the `/private` directory will not be a problem. This is just a very peculiar issue. :-)

Comment: Please specify the directory from which you are executing `docker` command. Check above thread

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Docker: "lstat no such file or directory" error when building image. File is there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36180296/docker-lstat-no-such-file-or-directory-error-when-building-image-file-is-the)

Comment: @DigvijayS unfortunately, I'm using a pre-built image straight from Postgres, so no Dockerfile or build context is involved. Updating the question with the directory this is run from.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, silly me. `dump.sql` was named `backup.sql`. I don't know how many hours I spent on this... Always start with the most obvious stuff, folks. Case closed.